# Draw text along a path on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, text

I am developing a map App in windows phone 7.5 platform. I need draw a text along some road. In the android, I can create a Path object and assigned start and end points with it. And then I can call the drawTextOnPath API to draw the text along the path. But I don't know how to implement this in windows phone. It seems that I can only use TextBlock to draw text on WritableBitmap, but the TextBlock class does not provide API to change the orient of text. Must I use the XNA to draw the text?

**EDIT1:** I am not using any Map srevice such as Bing and the Map control to implement my app. Because the App just provides map of our school campus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the article :http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Map-Control-Display-Current-Location-and-Remove-previous-Pushpins

is very useful

....................................2

o  you want to find a way to draw path on writebitmap.

you can draw path on the parent control of the writebitmap.

like this:

var yourpath
  = XamlReader.Load(@"") as Path;

Children.Add(_pathUnreadTriangle);

And MeasureOverride it

Comment: Hi MengMeng, Thanks for your answer, but I am not using the Map Control and any map service such as Bing while I draw my own map by programming. I am so sorry for unclear statement and I will modify the question. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, what I want to do is draw a Text string with a specific orientation just like along a path. You must saw a map that draw a text but not 90 degree horizon or vertical.